# Не работает метод compareTo для сортировки массива [JAVA]

Tags: java

Хочу отсортировать массив с помощью метода compareTo по имени и фамилии - не выходит, по среднему баллу (AveMark) тоже, хотя НУЖНО по нему (среднему баллу) отсортировать массив. Помогите пожалуйста

Main.java

```
    package com.company;

    public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student st1 = new Student("Nastia","Polishuk", 1.2, true);
    Student st2 = new Student("Pavlo","Kush",1.3, false);
    Student st3 = new Student("Ksenia","Lazar", 1.1, true);
    Student st4 = new Student("Artem","Germanchuk", 1.4, true);
    Student st5 = new Student("Olga","Levan", 2.3, true);
    Student st6 = new Student("Artur","Jun", 2.1, false);
    Student st7 = new Student("Liza","Osadchuk", 1.9, true);
    Student st8 = new Student("Masha","Rubachok", 2.4, true);
    Student st9 = new Student("Katya","Pisarchuk", 2.6, true);
    Student st10 = new Student("Sasha","Tushenko", 2.5, false);
    Student st11 = new Student("Victor","Nazarchuk", 3.1, true);
    Student st12 = new Student("Lubov","Po", 3.2, true);
    Student st13 = new Student("Asya","Lubid", 3.7, true);
    Student st14 = new Student("Nazar","Pulupchuk", 3.4, false);
    Student st15 = new Student("Enver","Kozachok", 4.1, true);
    Student st16 = new Student("Vova","Desnov", 3.5, true);
    Student st17 = new Student("Dima","Korolenko", 4.2, true);
    Student st18 = new Student("Diana","Yovko", 4.9, false);
    Student st19 = new Student("Marina","Mereshko", 1.7, true);
    Student st20 = new Student("Ulyana","Gerasumchuk", 5.0, true);

    Student arr[] = new Student[20];

    arr[0] = st1;
    arr[1] = st2;
    arr[2] = st3;
    arr[3] = st4;
    arr[4] = st5;
    arr[5] = st6;
    arr[6] = st7;
    arr[7] = st8;
    arr[8] = st9;
    arr[9] = st10;
    arr[10] = st11;
    arr[11] = st12;
    arr[12] = st13;
    arr[13] = st14;
    arr[14] = st15;
    arr[15] = st16;
    arr[16] = st17;
    arr[17] = st18;
    arr[18] = st19;
    arr[19] = st20;

    System.out.println("                         М А С И В  Д О  С О Р Т У В А Н Н Я: " + "\n");
    PrintArr(arr);

    System.out.println("                   М А С И В  П І С Л Я  С О Р Т У В А Н Н Я (вставками): " + "\n");
    StudentInsetSorting(arr);
    PrintArr(arr);

    System.out.println("                      І Н Д Е К С  Ш У К А Н О Г О  С Т У Д Е Н Т А ");
    System.out.println("                           З  С Е Р Е Д Н І М  Б А Л О М  4.2 : " + "\n");
    int index =(int) InterpolationSearch(arr, 4.2);
    System.out.println(index);

    System.out.println("                        М А С И В  П І С Л Я  В И Д А Л Е Н Н Я: ");
    Remove(arr, index);
}
public static void StudentInsetSorting(Student[] arr){// сортування вставками
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i){
        int j = i-1;
        Student key = arr[i]; //ми беремо один елемент масиву (спочатку перший, потім другий і т.д.)
        while(j >= 0 && key.compareTo(arr[j]) == -1){ //а тоді, порівнюючи з усіма попередніми, знаходимо йому місце
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            --j;          // j = -1 для того щоб далі змінити місцями з елементом
        }
        arr[j+1] = key; //вставляємо елемент якому знайшли місце
    }
}
public static double InterpolationSearch(Student[] arr, double AveMarkToSearch) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int lastIndex = arr.length -1;
    while((startIndex <= lastIndex) && (AveMarkToSearch >= arr[startIndex].AverageMark()) && AveMarkToSearch <= arr[lastIndex].AverageMark()) {
        // используем формулу интерполяции для поиска возможной лучшей позиции для существующего элемента
        int pos =(int)( startIndex + (((lastIndex-startIndex) /
                ((arr[lastIndex].AverageMark() - arr[startIndex].AverageMark()))*(AveMarkToSearch - arr[startIndex].AverageMark()))));

        if (arr[pos].AverageMark() == AveMarkToSearch)
            return pos;
        if (arr[pos].AverageMark() < AveMarkToSearch)
            startIndex = (int) (pos + 1);

        else
            lastIndex = (int) (pos - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
public static void Remove(Student [] arr, int index) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if( i == index && arr[i].playOnMusicInstruments() == true) {
            Student[] copy = new Student[arr.length-1];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copy, 0, i);
            System.arraycopy(arr, i+1, copy, i, arr.length-i-1);
            PrintArr(copy);
        }
    }
}
public static void PrintArr(Student[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + arr[i].name() + "," + " surname: " + arr[i].surname() + "," +
                " average mark: " + arr[i].AverageMark() + "," + " Play on music instruments: " + arr[i].playOnMusicInstruments());
    }
}}
```

student.java

```
    package com.company;

    public class Student implements Comparable <Student> {
private String name;
private String surname;
private double AverageMark;
private boolean playMusic;

public Student(String name, String surname, double averMark, boolean playMusic){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.AverageMark = averMark;
    this.playMusic = playMusic;
}

@Override
    //реализуем метод compareTo интерфейса Comparable
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    //используем метод compareTo из класса String для сравнения имен
    int result = this.name.compareTo(o.name);

    //если имена одинаковые -  сравниваем возраст, используя метод compareTo из класса Integer

    if (result == 0) {
        result = this.surname.compareTo(o.surname);
    }
    return result;
}

    public String name () {
        return name;
    }
    public String surname () {
        return surname;
    }

    public double AverageMark () {
        return AverageMark;
    }

    public boolean playOnMusicInstruments () {
        return playMusic;
    }


    }
```

Comment: "сравниваем возраст" - где?

Comment: странный какой-то у вас метод компарации

Answer (score 1):

В программировании все строится на использовании неких "правил и стандартов", что дает очень широкие возможности.
1)Методы и перемнные именуются с маленьких букв верблюжей нотацией.
2)Для получения доступа к приватным полям существуют методы, называемые геттерами, их сигнатура давно определена и менять это не стоит.
3)Изобретение велосипеда не приветствуется и является антипаттерном.Это означает, что писать свои методы сортировки или делать что-либо подобное не стоит.
4)Для работы с полями существуют методы, что соответсвует паттерну GRASP, который именуется Information expert. Это же относится и к методу toString, переопределяемому с целью получения строчного представления ваших объектов (проще говоря определяет, каким образом будут отображаться ваши объекты при выводе в консоль).
5)Существует такой принцип как KISS , что на русском означает "сделай это проще". Чем лаконичнее ваш код, тем он легче читается, следовательно, его проще дебажить, рефакторить и т.д.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Student[] arr = createArray(
                new Student("Nastia", "Polishuk", 1.2, true),
                new Student("Pavlo", "Kush", 1.3, false),
                new Student("Ksenia", "Lazar", 1.1, true),
                new Student("Artem", "Germanchuk", 1.4, true),
                new Student("Olga", "Levan", 2.3, true),
                new Student("Artur", "Jun", 2.1, false),
                new Student("Liza", "Osadchuk", 1.9, true),
                new Student("Masha", "Rubachok", 2.4, true),
                new Student("Katya", "Pisarchuk", 2.6, true),
                new Student("Sasha", "Tushenko", 2.5, false),
                new Student("Victor", "Nazarchuk", 3.1, true),
                new Student("Lubov", "Po", 3.2, true),
                new Student("Asya", "Lubid", 3.7, true),
                new Student("Nazar", "Pulupchuk", 3.4, false),
                new Student("Enver", "Kozachok", 4.1, true),
                new Student("Vova", "Desnov", 3.5, true),
                new Student("Dima", "Korolenko", 4.2, true),
                new Student("Diana", "Yovko", 4.9, false),
                new Student("Marina", "Mereshko", 1.7, true),
                new Student("Ulyana", "Gerasumchuk", 5.0, true)
        );

        System.out.println("                         М А С И В  Д О  С О Р Т У В А Н Н Я:\n");
        printArray(arr);

        System.out.println("\n                   М А С И В  П І С Л Я  С О Р Т У В А Н Н Я:\n");
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        printArray(arr);

        System.out.println("\n                        М А С И В  П І С Л Я  В И Д А Л Е Н Н Я:\n");
        printArray(remove(arr, s -> s.isPlayMusic() && s.getAverageMark() == 4.2));
        
    }
    
    private static <T> Object[] remove(T[] arr, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(predicate).toArray();
    }
    
    private static <T> T[] createArray(T ... args) {
        return args;
    }
    
    private static <T> void printArray(T ... array) {
        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}

class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private double averageMark;
    private boolean playMusic;

    public Student(String name, String surname, double averageMark, boolean playMusic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.averageMark = averageMark;
        this.playMusic = playMusic;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public double getAverageMark() {
        return averageMark;
    }

    public boolean isPlayMusic() {
        return playMusic;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student) {
        int result = Double.compare(this.averageMark, student.averageMark);
        if (result != 0) return result;
        result = this.surname.compareTo(student.surname);
        if (result != 0) return result;
        return this.name.compareTo(student.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "," + " surname: " + surname + "," + 
                " average mark: " + averageMark + "," + " Play on music instruments: " + playMusic;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: @Колесник Юрій да не за что, удачи в изучении java

Answer (score 0):

Обычно функция компаратор должна возвращать такие значения: `1, 0, -1`

Сортируем по среднему баллу:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return Double.compare(this.AverageMark, o.AverageMark);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!